# How is the Tumbleweed badge awarded?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I have been searching through meta trying to find out what the exact number of views is that constitutes "low views."  Is there an algorithm that determines when the Tumbleweed badge is programmatically awarded?  Or does someone go through questions and manually award the badges to questions they think meet the criteria?

Comment: @Barry. I saw that but it did not seem to definitively answer the question of an exact amount.  The accepted answer seemed speculative.

Comment: @YWE - The exact number of views, for whatever reason, seems to be unknown.  I think it's fair to say around 12-14 views is classed as low.  However, if you look at Jeffs answer, he says that the test for number of views could be removed and the number of badges awarded would remain the same.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me unless the number of views was not taken into account at all.

Comment: @YWE Jeff is saying that if a question has no votes, answers or comments, it's very likely that it also has low views.